# Is there a way to get the memory address of any object as an NSString?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I need to store the memory address of an Object as an NSString. Is there a special format specifier for that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`%p` should work for any pointer, including pointers to objects. So:

```
NSString *addr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%p", obj];
```

That will be a string beginning with `0x` and in hexadecimal.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use the `%p` formatter to get the address of an object as a string. Something like this would work:

```
NSString *pstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%p", myPtr];
```